# Getting name of local variable at runtime in Python3

Tags: python, local-variables

I want to get variable name in function so here:

```
def foo(bar):
    print(getLocalVaribalename(bar))
```

I want 'bar' to be printed.
so I found the code for global variables

```
def varName(variable,globalOrLocal=globals()):
    for name in list(globalOrLocal.keys()):
        expression = f'id({name})'
        if id(variable) == eval(expression):
            return name
```

and I sent `varName(bar,locals())` to it like this

```
def foo(bar):
    print(varName(bar,locals()))
```

but gives `NameError: name 'bar' is not defined` error.

I also found [Getting name of local variable at runtime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583505/getting-name-of-local-variable-at-runtime-in-python) which is for python 2 but the syntax is completely different. note that the main goal is to get the name of local variable and not necessarily with this code(varName function which is defined few lines earlier).

Comment: Short of using `inspect` to look at the source code itself, you can't do this. Objects don't have any information about what name(s) refer to them.

Comment: There's no reason, outside of writing a debugger, you should *want* to do this. If the name of the variable matters, you should be using a `dict` instead.

Comment: note that the main goal is to get the name of local variable and not necessarily with this code(varName function which is defined few lines earlier).

Comment: You *have* the name of the local variable: you typed it as the argument for `getLocalVariableName`. Again: the function receives the *value* of the variable, with no information about the variable itself.

Comment: thanx @chepner but I don't upvote you right now until to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
def getlocalnamesforobj(obj):
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    return [key for key, value in frame.f_locals.items() if value is obj]
```

This introspects the local variables from the calling function.
One obvious problem is, of course, there might be more than one name pointing to the same object, so the function returns a list of names.

As put in the comments, however, I can't perceive how this can be of any use in any real code.

As a rule of thumb, if you need variable names as data (strings), you probably should be using a dictionary to store your data instead.

Comment: thanx for answer, but what are these frames? ofc I don't want the full explanation, but how can I learn more about what those are, or give me some keyword or source.

Comment: Frames are Python objects the language creates whenever entering in an execution scope (for example, entering a function); they hold references to the code object being executed, local variables and global variables + some helpers, and are fully introspectable for reading from within Python itself. The module "inspect" has some other helper functions to retrieve Frame objects. The "1" passed retrieves the frame prior to the current one, which would be inside the running function itself. Exception stacktraces and debuggers make use of Frames.

Comment: Keep in mind that frames are an implementation detail of CPython, not something guaranteed to exist by the language. From the documentation: "CPython implementation detail: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python."

Comment: indeed, but they have been quite a consistent implementation detail - and other implementations seeking fully compatibility end up implementing then as well. I would not try frames in Brython or Micropython, but pypy has then (and I use then in packages targeting both pypy and cPython)